# Why some sites load like an SPA while some refreshes everytime?

Tags: performance, vue.js, nuxt.js, single-page-application, web-hosting

I have hosted my website on two different providers

- render - https://madhusudanlive.onrender.com/
- railway - https://krypton.up.railway.app/

Both of these sites have same code and built on top of nuxtJS, also the same methods used for deploying, but the one hosted on the render loads quickly, and the loading sign on URL doesn't change (feels like an SPA) but the other one reloads page on every single request, and we can clearly see the reload and cross icons changing on every click.

For a better example, open the navbar on top right and click the home/about pages, and then click on the k logo, for `render` site, it will show animation but for the `railway` host, it will not show the animation but reload the page.

Comment: Do you at least have some public github repo?

Comment: I voted to close this question because is about debugging a problem but has no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

The app on Render is indeed an SPA, the Railway one behaves like an MPA.
I can confirm that.

As of the exact reason, we'll need to check some of your code. What matters the most is how it behaves if you bundle (and preview) it locally.

Also, depends if you use `'server'` or `'static'` for those as a `target`.
Also how you configured the deploy on each platform.

PS: I would start by fixing those errors first is quite important.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but the configs for both are same, both are deployed with target `server` I used same build configuration, still both of these sites behaves differently.

Comment: @krypton still not enough info here. What is inside of your SFC files? Does it behave like that locally? What about your `nuxt.config.js` setup? How do you try it locally? As of right now, your issue is not answerable so far. And nobody will take the time to kinda replicate your issue on both PaSS just for giggles. Please put in some effort.